# How can I make the time to be the last on my beamer title slide?

Tags: beamer, titles

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
    \title{Presentation title}
    \author{Author name}
    \titlegraphic{Name of the consulant}
    \institute{Name of the institute}
    \date{The date}
\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image: title slide]

I have this title page, but I want the date to be the last one, not the consulant. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you just using the default [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) theme?

Comment: No, but I thought it would be easier just to show a part of my code and the answer would be universal

Comment: Does your `\date` appear anywhere else than on the `\titlepage`?

Comment: Just on the titlepage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sticking to the default [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) theme, then you can just switch the content for `\titlegraphic` and `\date`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Presentation title}
\author{Author name}
\date{Name of the consulant}
\institute{Name of the institute}
\titlegraphic{The date}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You're already using `\titlegraphic` for something other than a *graphic* associated with the *title*, so swapping around the use of `\date` and `\titlegraphic` should not be an issue.

The above approach would, of course, provide problems if used in a theme that displays the `\date` on places other than just the `\titlepage`.

Comment: This is way more than a hack, this is lovely ;)